# Is there a relationship between depth/diameter/etc... of meteoric craters and the strength (eg:compressive strength) of the target material (sand...)?

Tags: materials, civil-engineering, strength

So I am trying to write a high school research paper (3700 words) on the topic above. I am not sure if there is such a relationship, but I think intuitively we can agree that different materials will react differently to a meteor impact (especially in small lab size experiments since they are in what is called in the strength regime as opposed to gravity). I think a relationship exists because of the Newton-Laplace equation : [image]

So perhaps someone can shed light on how impact craters inform us about the target material's mechanical properties ?

Comment: Check out the physics stack or bombs...

Comment: Cross posted here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/497026

Comment: And also here https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33052

Comment: Oh these are on a different topic, and it seems that the others are rather complicated for my level so I wanna see if I can research this topic instead.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the paper by Turtle, E. P., et al. "[Impact structures: What does crater diameter mean](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gordon_Osinski/publication/253750582_Impact_Structures_What_Does_Crater_Diameter_Mean/links/0deec538cb4fbbf71c000000/Impact-Structures-What-Does-Crater-Diameter-Mean.pdf)." Large meteorite impacts III 384 (2005): 1-24.

After reading the paper, look at the list of references and try to locate the papers that seem to be most relevant from your local library (or e-mail the corresponding author).  That will give you an understanding of the complexity of the problem and the best one can do with a small amount of information.

In particular, if you are considering impacts into granular materials, you can look at the introductory parts of Omidvar, Mehdi, Magued Iskander, and Stephan Bless. "[Response of granular media to rapid penetration](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Magued_Iskander/publication/259515946_Response_Of_Granular_Media_To_Rapid_Penetration/links/5a24a31faca2727dd87e545a/Response-Of-Granular-Media-To-Rapid-Penetration.pdf)." International Journal of Impact Engineering 66 (2014): 60-82.

Another readable source is Collins, Gareth S., H. Jay Melosh, and Gordon R. Osinski. "The impact-cratering process." Elements 8.1 (2012): 25-30.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I have been reading on what is called Impact strength and the Izod Impact test, do you think this concept can be applied to granular media even though the Izod Impact test is applied horizontally instead of vertically like an actual impact meteorite? And if yes would that involve taking the granular media to be a continuous mass?

Comment: Izod and Charpy impact experiments test for a quantity called "dynamic fracture toughness" that makes sense for solid materials but not for granular materials.  Granular media are intermediate between solid and fluid and have to be treated accordingly. Also, these tests do not deliver any information that can be used for cratering prediction.  The orientation of the test does not make too much of a difference.